# what does document.createElement("_") do in javascript

Tags: javascript, createelement

Please have a look at https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/blob/master/classList.js :

```
if ("document" in self && !("classList" in document.createElement("_"))) {
  //...
}
```

What is the purpose of `document.createElement("_")`? I know it creates an html element, but why use `_` instead of an html element name?

Comment: *So many?* Could you provide couple of examples?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't seen `document.createElement(_)`?

Comment: @Teemu  have a look at https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/blob/master/classList.js

Comment: That expression just sniffs, if [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement) has `classList` property, there could be any string within the parens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It creates an element with the tag <_>. I see no reasonable purpose to this.